# Create pager from db_query

Tags: 7, theming, paging

This my SQL query to fetch the details.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/(
        SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per
        FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW
        WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0'
        GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE
        ORDER BY TITLE ASC";
        $res = db_query($query);
```

I am displaying out put like this

```
foreach ($res as $row) { 
$i++; ?>
<li>
<a href="/page-file-views-user?id=<?php echo $row->pid ;?>&type=<?php echo $row->type; ?>" >
<ul class="inner-ul">
<li class="name"><?php echo ucfirst($row->title); ?></li>
<li class="percentage">
<ul>
<li><?php echo $row->per * 100; ?>%</li>
<li><?php echo $row->tot; ?></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</a>
</li>
<?php $sum+= $row->tot; } ?>
```

How can I add a pagination (mini pager) at top & bottom of the result?

`<?php 
function pager_array_splice($data, $limit = 9, $element = 0) {

  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
  $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
 // Convert comma-separated $page to an array, used by other functions.
  $pager_page_array = explode(',', $page); // outs puts empty array
  // We calculate the total of pages as ceil(items / limit).
  $pager_total_items[$element] = count($data); // output 1 
  $pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit); // output 1 
  $pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min((int)$pager_page_array[$element], ((int)$pager_total[$element]) - 1));  // no output
  return array_slice($data, $pager_page_array[$element] * $limit, $limit, TRUE);
}
?>`

And in my pagination div

`$output = '';
$customArr = pager_array_splice($data, 1);
$output .= theme('views_mini_pager', array('quantity' => 1));
print $output;`

But no result is printing. Any error in my logic.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take advantage of the [PagerDefault](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/class/PagerDefault/7) class.

Write your query as a db_select query which I'll leave as an exercise for the reader because, frankly, I'm not sure if it's possible to create a db_select query with a subquery as part of an expression like that :).  Assuming you build up your select query in a variable called $query, you'd have code along these lines:

```
$query = db_select('REPORT_LIST_VIEW')->extend('PagerDefault');
...build up $query object here...
$res = $query->execute();

$pager = drupal_render(array('#theme' => 'pager'));
```

Then just output $pager wherever you want it.

Also, in general, I'd recommend placing this in a block rather than hard-coding it into your theme so that it's more reusable.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Can i use the same query structure to build the pager. I know i need more code to execute it.

Comment: Here's the SelectQuery documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7  and here's some info on how to build dynamic queries (which is what you need to do): https://www.drupal.org/dynamic-queries

Comment: I am getting all the results properly. I need a pagination to reduce the  page load and length. Once the `$res = db_query($query)`, i am using `foreach ($res as $row) { ...}` to display result. On the top and bottom of results, i need to add pager. If its difficult to done by drupal API, can be implemented by PHP SQL pagination.

Comment: Well, my answer focuses on how to use the Drupal API to create a pager.  If you're going to write a pager from scratch that's a much longer answer that I'll leave someone else to tackle.